# CentOS 5.4 No package qemu available

Tags: centos, yum, qemu

I'm trying to install qemu on CentOS 5.4(final) with:

```
yum install qemu
```

The result is:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * addons: mirror.steadfast.net
 * base: mirrors.cat.pdx.edu
 * extras: mirror.rocketinternet.net
 * updates: mirror.rocketinternet.net
Excluding Packages from CentOS-5 - Base
Finished
Excluding Packages from CentOS-5 - Updates
Finished
Setting up Install Process
No package qemu available.
Nothing to do
```

Can anybody help me please? What repository should I add?

Answer (score 2):

qemu has been [moved to the centosplus repository, as it conflicts with the kvm-qemu-img package](http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=4111).

Comment: Does anyone have any additional information on this?